# Ending of Cruella

Tags: realism, ending, cruella

At the end of [Cruella (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3228774/):

> The Baroness pushes Estella off a cliff and is arrested for murder. Since Estella is the biological daughter of the Baroness, and since "Estella willed her fortune to her dear friend Cruella de Vil", Cruella de Vil (who in reality is the non-death Estella) "inherits" the Baroness's fortune.

Is this according to the law? That is, does a woman who murders her daughter, go to prison and lose her fortune to her daughter's heir? According to Wikipedia, the movie is set in 1970s London, so the laws of such time and place apply.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a lawyer, nor do I have any specific knowledge about legal changes between the 70s & today…

I'm not sure the murder would affect this. The law can generally only take the estate of a convicted person if their wealth was itself illegally gained.

However, when a beneficiary pre-deceases, the gift is returned to the estate. [There's a grey area if they live a short time after, but that doesn't apply in this case]. You can't inherit if you're already dead.

If Estella willed her estate to Cruella, then Cruella would get whatever Estella was worth, not what the Baroness was worth. The Baroness's gift would not proceed.

As it's a question that crops up regularly in real life, it's quite easy to find easily-comprehensible versions of this at UK law firms - see [Co-Op Legal - What Happens in Probate if a Beneficiary Has Died?](https://www.co-oplegalservices.co.uk/media-centre/articles-jan-march-2019/what-happens-in-probate-if-a-beneficiary-has-died/)

Comment: I see but this is not a probate situation, because the Baroness did not die. "The law can generally only take the estate of a convicted person if their wealth was itself illegally gained." -> What if the Baroness's fortune was taken as a compensation to Cruella for the death of Estella ? It surely happens that the law impose to a murderer to compensate the family of the victim. The only problem here is that Cruella was not Estella's family but only in Estella's will.

Comment: If the Baroness is still alive, then there is no estate yet to inherit. The law can't take it away from her. Any compensation would have to be a civil case, brought to court separately. Basically you can't inherit from someone who is alive & you can't inherit if you're dead.

Comment: So the most realistic explanation would be that Cruella sued the Baroness for Estella's death and won, getting the Baroness fortune as compensation

Comment: It's not much more realistic than making fur coats out of dalmations… I haven't seen it yet, so I don't know what detail is in the story